# Nested query is throwing Error Code: 1054 (unknown column)

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

```
SELECT 
    booking.batch_id,
    (SELECT 
            COALESCE(JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE('[]',
                                CONCAT('[',
                                        GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_ARRAY(v0)
                                            SEPARATOR ','),
                                        ']')),
                        JSON_ARRAY())
        FROM
            (SELECT 
                booking_additions.order_id AS v0
            FROM
                booking_additions
            WHERE
                (booking_additions.order_id = booking.order_id)) AS t) AS bookingadditions
FROM
    booking AS booking
WHERE
    booking.batch_id > 0;
```

I am trying to run this query but for some reason, I am getting errors that
`Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'booking.order_id' in 'where clause'`. Could someone help me why `booking.order_id` is not accessible in the nested query?

`MySQL version: 5.7.35`

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Answer (score 1):

That innermost table can only see the middle table, not the outermost.

Rewrite the query to have less depth.  Perhaps this works??

```
SELECT  booking.batch_id, 
        (
            SELECT  COALESCE(JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE('[]', CONCAT('[', 
                  GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_ARRAY(booking_additions.order_id)
                               SEPARATOR ','),       ']'
                                                )            ),
                         JSON_ARRAY() )
            FROM  booking_additions AS ba
            WHERE ba.order_id = b.order_id)
        ) AS bookingadditions
    FROM  booking AS b
    WHERE  b.batch_id > 0;
```